# Saving JSON files directly to Blob Storage using PowerShell

Tags: azure-blob-storage, powershell-3.0, azure-powershell, blobstorage

I would like to save JSON files from an API call directly to Blob Storage rather than saving the files to local folder and transferring it to Blob Storage.

My code below calls an API and then saves it to a local folder. Is it possible to save it directly to Blob Storage via PowerShell

```
$logPath = 'C:\Dev\Template\Test'

$access_token ="Access_Token"

$URI =  "https://XXXXX"
$headers = @{“authorization” = “Bearer $access_token”} 
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URI -Headers $headers -ContentType $ContentType |ConvertTo-Json
$Result|ConvertFrom-Json| Select -ExpandProperty Forms| Out-File "$logPath\$report_iu.json"
```

Comment: Please feel free to let me know if you  have any problem.

Comment: "D:\FIle\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll" is this looking at my local computer? I need the JSON files generated straight into Blob Storage. Let me know if my understanding is incorrect.

Comment: Yes, the `D:\FIle\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll` is mean intall your Storage package in your local, so you could use Storage property. And after running the code as below, you could generate json file straight in blob.

Comment: Any update now? If it helps you, please mark it as answer.

Comment: If I need to run D:\FIle\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll in my local computer what happens if someone else needs to run the code from another machine? Will it still work or if I leave the organisation?

Answer (score 0):

You could convert result to json and use [UploadText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob._cloud_block_blob.uploadtext?view=azure-java-legacy) to upload it to Azure storage.

```
#get the json
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URI -Headers $headers -ContentType $ContentType |ConvertTo-Json

#load the blob storage module
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("D:\FIle\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll")
$connstr="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountNamexxx;AccountKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
$storageAccount = [microsoft.windowsazure.storage.cloudstorageaccount]::parse($connstr)
$blobclient=$storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient()
$cloudBlobContainer = $blobclient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer")
$cloudBlockBlob = $cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("my.json")

#upload json to blob storage
$cloudBlockBlob.UploadText($result)
```